# Two outdoor sports

Tags: riddle, knowledge, sports

*There are two outdoor sports.*

*If we take away the middle from the first sport, it indicates a forty.*

*If we change the ending of the second sport, it indicates a fifty.*

***Which are those sports?***

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If we remove the middle of..

> **RUGBY**, it becomes **RUBY**, which is a word for 40th anniversary.

If we change the ending of..

> **GOLF**, we can form **GOLD**, which indicates 50th anniversary.